# Pass data to next page in yii2

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am working on a project in Yii2
the requirement is when user clicks on a row in gridview , it should open a new controller called check in and display all the users checked in for that particular row.

I am confused rather to use `actioncolumn` and crete a new button or use `rowopions`

Anyway when i use `rowoptions` like this

```
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'template' => '{index} {view} {update} {delete} ',
            'buttons' => [

                'index' => function ($url,$model) {

                    return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>', $url);

                },
            ]

        ],
```

When i use that code with the javascript

```
<?php
        $this->registerJs("
            $('tbody td').css('cursor', 'pointer');
            $('tbody td').click(function (e) {
                var id = $(this).closest('tr').data('id');
            if (e.target == this)
                location.href = '" . Url::to(['checkin/index' ]) . "?id=' + id;
            });
        ");
    ?>
```

It gives the id on the row click event happens but it does not redirect to "`checkin/index`" page
it refreshes on the same age and the row id is attached at the end of the url.

But when i use this script

```
 <?php
    $this->registerJs("

        $('td').click(function (e) {
            var id = $(this).closest('tr').data('id');
            if(e.target == this)
                location.href = '" . Url::to(['checkin/index']) . "?id=' + id;
        });

    ");
?>
```

It redirects to the `checkin/index` page fine 
but url doesnt get any `id`
its displays `checkin/index/id=undefined`

I want to pass the id to the `checkinSearch` controller and only displays the clicked row's data to the use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this..
E.g.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'rowOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index, $grid) {
                        return ['id' => $model['student_id'], 'class' => 'action-tr', 'data-link' => urldecode(Url::toRoute(['/student/student-transaction/update', 'id' => $model['student_id']]))];
    },
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        [
          'attribute' => 'student_roll_no',
          'value' => 'rel_Stud_Info.student_roll_no',
        ],
        [
          'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
          'template' => '{update} {delete}',
          'contentOptions' => ['class'=>'action-td'],       
        ],
    ],
]); ?>
```

And Register below Js for prevent `ActionColumn` to redirect row click.

```
<?php
    $this->registerJs("
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.action-tr').on('click', 'td:not(.action-td)', function(){

            //get the link from data attribute
            var the_link = $(this).parent().attr('data-link');

            //do we have a valid link      
            if (the_link == '' || typeof the_link === 'undefined') {
            //do nothing for now
            }
            else {
            //open the page
            window.location = the_link;
            }
        });
    });
"); ?>
```

This example is part of real project and works for me.
Try it....

Comment: If you do not register above js so, when you click on `ActionColumn` you redirect to row url instead of `ActionColumn` button link.

Comment: seems to have the same problem.. it refreshes on same page and attach the row clicked data's id with url... this is what i did to solve the problem. `'onclick' =>'location.href="'.Url::to(['checkin/index']).'?id="+(this.id);'` add that code to `rowoptioins` return statement and it solved the problem as of now but i want to do it using the ActionColumn instead row.. thank you any way